# Spy an already initialized Java object Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am using the Mocktio library to write some test cases, since I have an elaborate inhertance structure, I have a few objects which are instantiated in the parent class, and I would like to mock one of its function call. Does Mockito library provide any way to spy on a already initialized object?

Also, the object is not directly instantiable.

Similar to the following -

```
     public class A {
        protected static MyObject a;
        public static void someMethod() {
          a = myObjectBuilder.createObj(); 
        }
     }
```

And another class B looks something similar to

```
     class B  extends A {
       @BeforeClass
       public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
          someMethod();
       }
       @Test
       public void mockTest() { 
         // now mock behavior  of some method of MyObject a
         // Missing line to spy object a.
         Mockito.doReturn(false).when(a).xyz();
         /* Now call some method that triggers a.xyz() 
            again, it is not a direct call,
            there are multiple layer of abstraction 
         */
       }
     }
```

Edit: I have tried the following and it does not work

```
   MyObject mock_object = Mockito.spy(a);
   Mockito.doReturn(false).when(mock_object).xyz();
```

Comment: Use `Type spiedInstance = Mockito.spy(instance);`

Comment: I did try that, it did not work and logically it should not work right. Since the method would be getting called on the original instance (a) and not spiedInstance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, don't do initialisation in BeforeClass, it runs only once but
you need to have new spy in each test, or you must "reinitialise" spy object
before each test.
Please examine this code:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class MyObject{
    public String cos;

    public MyObject(String cos) {
        this.cos = cos;
    }

    public boolean xyz() {
        return true;
    }
}

class A {
    protected static MyObject a;
    public void someMethod() {
        a = new MyObject("cccc");
    }
}

public class B  extends A {
    @Before
    public void setUpBeforeTest() {
        someMethod();
    }
    @Test
    public void mockTest() {
        MyObject mock_object = Mockito.spy(a);
        Mockito.doReturn(false).when(mock_object).xyz();
        assertThat(mock_object.xyz()).isFalse();
    }
    @Test
    public void mockTest2() {
        MyObject mock_object = Mockito.spy(a);
        Mockito.doReturn(true).when(mock_object).xyz();
        assertThat(mock_object.xyz()).isTrue();
    }

}
```

If you want it your way, please change:

```
public void someMethod() {
      a = myObjectBuilder.createObj(); 
}
```

into:

```
public static void someMethod() {
      a = myObjectBuilder.createObj(); 
}
```

You can't call non static method from static initialiser  @BeforeClass:

```
class A {
    protected static MyObject a;
    public static void someMethod() {
        a = new MyObject("cccc");
    }
}

public class B  extends A {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
        someMethod();
    }
    @Test
    public void mockTest() {
        MyObject mock_object = Mockito.spy(a);
        Mockito.doReturn(false).when(mock_object).xyz();
        assertThat(mock_object.xyz()).isFalse();
    }

@Test
public void mockTest2() {
    MyObject mock_object = Mockito.spy(a);
    // Here we replace original object with our spy
    A.a = mock_object;
    Mockito.doReturn(false).when(mock_object).xyz();
    assertThat(a.xyz()).isFalse();
}
}
```

Another example (in this case we replace object **a** with mock (spy is not needed):

```
class MyObject{
    public String cos;

    public MyObject(String cos) {
        this.cos = cos;
    }

    public boolean xyz() {
        return true;
    }
}

class A {
    protected MyObject a;

    public A() {
        a = new MyObject("ggggg");
    }

    public String doSomethingWithA(){
        if(a.xyz()){
            return a.cos;
        }
        else{
            return "aaaa";
        }
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class B  {

    @Mock
    MyObject mock_object;

    @InjectMocks
    A systemUnderTest = new A();

    @Test
    public void mockTest1() {
        Mockito.doReturn(false).when(mock_object).xyz();
        assertThat(systemUnderTest.doSomethingWithA()).isEqualTo("aaaa");
    }
    @Test
    public void mockTest2() {
        Mockito.doReturn(true).when(mock_object).xyz();
        assertThat(systemUnderTest.doSomethingWithA()).isNull();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, actually I was trying to show the Mockito approach, the function I have declared is static itself (edited the code). And as mentioned in the comments, I tried to use this method but it does not work. As the xyz() method is being called on the actual object 'a' and not the mock_object

Comment: In our examples we create spy outside your multiple layered complicated object structure. You should find way to insert this spy back into this complicated structure. Without this it basically won't work, because original object structure do not know nothing about this new spy object.
Probably you need also to mock/spy other "intermediary" objects.
Please see my example again. I modified second test in @BeforeClass example

Comment: I added another example, mayby you do not need a Spy at all.
Hard to say I do not see your real code.

Comment: Yes, I need to insert the spy back to the original structure. I do not think the second approach applies to my code but thank you for showing another approach to achieve it!